# UWPCommunityToolkit DropShadowPanel on Button

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to apply a shadow effect on a button on a UWP application.

I'm using the UWPCommunityToolkit tool and the control DropShadowPanel. Here an example :

http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/DropShadowPanel/

So my code for apply on a button control :

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="{Binding BlurRadius.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                              ShadowOpacity="{Binding Opacity.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                              OffsetX="{Binding OffsetX.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                              OffsetY="{Binding OffsetY.Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="My button" />
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

But the result is :

[image]

The shadow cover all my button control.

According to the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.aspx) Button control doesn't directy inherit from FrameworkElement, that is maybe a reason.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum problem solved by using custom values :

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0"
                              ShadowOpacity="0.70"
                              OffsetX="5.0"
                              OffsetY="5.0"
                              Color="Black"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="My button" Background="Aqua" />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

[image]